# Cannot install device driver for HighPoint rocket 640l, "ERROR: could not insert 'rr640l': No such device"

Tags: drivers, kernel, raid

Have been trying to install the drivers for HighPoint Rocket 650l in many different versions of Ubuntu (most lately server 13.04), with the same result every time. Doing `sudo modprobe rr640l` yields the following error message:

```
ERROR: could not insert 'rr640l': No such device
```

Building the module works flawlessly. The controller seems functional when I connect disks to it, they are accessible.

Doing `lspci` I can see it

```
02:00.0 SATA controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88SE9230 PCIe SATA 6Gb/s Controller (rev 11)
```

According to HighPoints website, the driver only works on kernels up to 3.17.3, which is why I am trying it on an older Ubuntu version.

My goal is to install a quick bios via their WebGUI RAID Management Interface, and in order to do so I must first get the driver to work.

uname -a resolves as

```
Linux com 3.8.0-19-generic #29-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 17 18:16:28 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Add the output of  `uname -a` to your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I made a mistake and attempted to install drivers for the rocketRAID 640l, not the rocket 640l. The rocket 640l should have native support in Linux, and cannot be reflashed  with another bios.